# Route planner for hiking in Slovenia (Triglav)

Tags: hiking, preparation

I'm looking for a route planner website for plannig hikes in Triglav National Park / Slovenia. I have used this site before, but cannot find it again.
I have used different search engines, looked in my browser history, used different keywords, but all I find is either an [online map](https://mapzs.pzs.si), commercial print maps, or apps that offer maps (e.g. komoot, locusmap).

This route planner allowed one to select two or more points, and it would give you several possible hiking routes that connect it. Just like a regular route planner, but for hiking trails in Slovenia.

Komoot does offer something vey similar, but if I remember correctly the website that I'm looking for was specific for Slovenia/Triglav National Park and also included trail closures, availability of via ferrata, and more detail overall. This made me feel that I could trust the map/route more than a "generic" planner such as komoot.

Would anyone happen to know the web address of this hiking route planner?

Comment: Doesn't komoot do exactly that?

Comment: Yes, more or less, but if I remember correctly this website that I'm looking for was specific for Slovenia/Triglav National Park and also included trail closures, availability of via ferrata,  and more detail overall. This made me feel that I could trust the map/route more than a "generic" planner such as komoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After numerous searches for "triglav route planner" I finally found the site by looking for "julian alps route planner" instead: https://julian-alps.com/en/tourplanner/